# Linker error LNK2019 when using DCMTK with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, lnk2019, dcmtk

This is not a new question but the solutions haven't worked for me. I want to read dicom files using C++. I have 32-bit Windows PC with VS 2013 community edition.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/810580/5022962) and other answers therein suggested using DCMTK. I installed DCMTK (using CMake followed by VS) and configured it for use with VS using guidelines and links provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12253663/5022962). Then I wrote a simple [test program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38258460/5022962) and tried to compile it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dcmtk\dcmdata\dctk.h"
#include "dcmtk\config\osconfig.h"
#include "dcmtk\dcmimgle\dcmimage.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DicomImage *image = new DicomImage("test.dcm");
    if (image != NULL)
    {
        if (image->getStatus() == EIS_Normal)
        {
            if (image->isMonochrome())
            {
                image->setMinMaxWindow();
                Uint8 *pixelData = (Uint8 *)(image->getOutputData(8 /* bits */));
                if (pixelData != NULL)
                {
                    /* do something useful with the pixel data */
                }
            }
        }
        else
            cerr << "Error: cannot load DICOM image (" << DicomImage::getString(image->getStatus()) << ")" << endl;
    }
    delete image; 
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compilation, it gives the following error:

```
dcmdata.lib(dcuid.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Netbios@4 referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl getMACAddress(unsigned char * const)" (?getMACAddress@@YAPAEQAE@Z)
```

This error seems to be common but none of the following solutions work for me:

1. [FAQ#27](http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=36) and [another post](http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=1285) of DCMTK forum: It suggests using particular order of lib files to be included. My order of including files is as follows (I tried the reverse order as well but it didn't work):

   [image]

All of this doesn't work. **In fact, I'm not sure which lib files are supposed to be included? How to decide that?**

I've also included "C:\Program Files\DCMTK\lib" under additional library directories and "C:\Program Files\DCMTK\include" under additional include directories in project properties.

2. [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31212164/5022962) at stackoverflow has not been answered. Comments suggest to re-run CMake by disabling DCMTK_OVERWRITE_WIN32_COMPILER_FLAGS. I didn't do it because the [DCMTK help page](http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_CMakeConfiguration360) says don't disable this unless you really know what you're doing.

Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. You can go to project properties-> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies-> Edit -> add these two libraries-( netapi32.lib,wsock32.lib) before all other libraries . This solved the error for me .

Answer (score 0):

The NetBios function resides in NETAPI32.LIB, so you can try moving NetAPI32.lib (which is in your list) to the top of that list.

Comment: I moved NETAPI32.lib to the top, keeping the rest of the list same but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of the DCMTK you use, but for the current development snapshot you need the following standard libraries (on Windows): "ws2_32 netapi32 wsock32". This information can be found in DCMTK's CMake files. By the way, you don't seem to use CMake for your project, right?

Comment: I use DCMTK 3.6.0 and I am using CMake. I tried including ws2_32 as well but it still doesn't work. (I looked into CmakeLists.txt to find this information, thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled dcmsign.lib as dcmsig.lib.

If changing that doesn't fix it, I would suggest the following order based on the support page that you linked to:
    NetAPI32.lib
    WSock32.lib
    ofstd.lib
    oflog.lib
    dcmdata.lib
    dcmsign.lib
    dcmnet.lib
    dcmsr.lib
    dcmqrdb.lib
    dcmtls.lib
    dcmwlm.lib
    dcmimgle.lib
    dcmpstat.lib
    dcmjpls.lib
    dcmjpeg.lib
    dcmimage.lib
    ijg16.lib
    ijg12.lib
    ijg8.lib

I think that in this list, each library has to come after all the libraries that it depends on.

Comment: In fact, I don't have any such file, dcmsign.lib. Instead I have dcmdsig.lib which is what I've mentioned. I also tried the order you've suggested and also included ws2_32.lib as suggested by @J. Riesmeier but it still doesn't work. For the order I followed this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/798086/5022962 but it seems to suggest the other way (as compared to what you say). I'm not sure which one is the correct so I've tried the reverse order as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the library name is actually "dcmdsig.lib", i.e. not identical to the name of DCMTK's module directory because of conflicts with the command line tool "dcmsign". Regarding the library order: as far as I know, Visual Studio is not that picky about it as gcc (or its linker) is. @ruchir Did you already enable the verbose mode of your linker?

Comment: @J.Riesmeier I've now enabled the verbose mode. Now I see over 3000 lines of output. Can this be used to locate the source of error?

Comment: @Ruchir Usually, yes. That's why I recommended it :) In the verbose output of the linker, you should be able to see which libraries are linked to your program from which directories, and of course, more details on your linker error. As you've said: the output is quite verbose, so you either need some experience or some patience in order to find the relevant lines.

Answer (score 0):

check your .lib and vs platform if the same ,such lib for x64, then your vs platform must be x64.

Comment: Yeah, both platforms are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by adding the additional dependency `iphlpapi.lib` in

Project Properties-> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies-> Edit -> add `iphlpapi.lib`